# SQL Server 2012 Enterprise - No Analysis Services on "Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server"

Tags: installation, upgrade, ssas, missing-features, ssas-2012

We upgraded our SQL Server 2012 Express Advanced edition to Enterprise and found No choce for Analysis Services when choosing "Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server"

We used these queries to confirm that the edition was the Enterprise edition.

```
--Version Number
select @@version

--Service Pack
select serverproperty('ProductLevel')

--Version Number
select serverproperty('ProductVersion')

--Edition
select serverproperty('Edition')
```

The queries returned:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (Intel X86) 
Feb 10 2012 19:13:17 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: Service Pack 1) (WOW64) (Hypervisor)

RTM

11.0.2100.60

Enterprise Edition
```

Can you tell me how to get the installer to allow us to install the Analysis Services? Reporting Services was there but not the Analysis Services.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue after upgrading as you did (i.e. 2012 Express Advanced to full Enterprise) - the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707783.aspx) says you can do this, but it also failed for me, i.e. can't install SSAS at all.  For reference, here's my version information.

[image]

Comment: Lynn, looks like we found a Microsoft installer bug. I wonder how other people are doing it and how many others are facing the same issue and how they solved it. I hope we don't need to uninstall the SQL Server and re-install it. That would mean a lot of backing up and will make a lot of people not happy with me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar situation with trying to get SSDT (SQL Server Data tools) edition to reflect the Enterprise editioni I installed. I had installed an enterprise edition right next to an Express edition. Even uninstalling the express edition did not work.

I had to run the installer and remove the "SSDT feature" that way and reinstall it via the Enterprise installer for it to recognize the correct edition intalling it. This did not require a full reinstall.
Let me know if that works... I'm assuming you figured out a workaround by this point though.